# what is the eigenvalue of shift operator?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that shift operators have no eigenvalues.
 the shift operator or translation operator is an operator that takes a function $f(x)$ to its translation $f(x+a)$.let $α$ be an eigenvalue of the shift operator $T$ ,.ie., $T(f)=αf$. Then 
$αf=f(x+a)$ and from here I do not know How do I get a contradiction?

Comment: Is $f$ a continuous function ? A bounded function ? A function in a $L^2$ space ?

Comment: You need more detail, there is not enough to guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should specify the domain of the operator. Regardless of the way it's defined, the claim is probably wrong. Let's say your looking at a function on $C(\mathbb{R})$ or $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$. Then every constant function is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue 1.

Comment: The way you are defining the shift function, any constant function is in fact an eigenfunction, with eigenvalue = 1.

Comment: Also, any function with period $a$ will also have an eigenvalue of 1.

Answer (score 6):

The statement that "shift operators have no eigenvalues" is almost exactly wrong.  In fact, every positive real number is an eigenvalue of a shift operator.  Given a shift $a$, take an arbitrary c.  Define
$$f(x)=e^{\ln{c}\frac{x}{a}}$$.
Then
$$f(x+a)=e^{\ln{c}\frac{x+a}{a}}$$
$$=e^{\ln{c}(1+\frac{x}{a})}$$
$$=e^{\ln c}e^{\ln{c}\frac{x}{a}}$$
$$=cf(x)$$
So $f(x)$ is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $c$.